# Getting System.Byte[] when exporting image from datagridview to excel in c#

Tags: c#, excel, windows, datagridview

I am working on exporting data from datagridview to excel.All the data is exported correctly without any errors but the problem that i get is that the image is shown with System.Byte[]. Is there any way to export image directly without downloading it to a particular path and upload it again?
Hope you help me this issue.

Comment: How about **unzip** a .xlsx file and the images are already there?

Comment: no, the same thing. I tried different ways but i got the same result in the image cell.

Comment: Do you have any **test cases**? maybe the answer has no relationship with excel.

Comment: All the datagridview whether varchar or int are shown while exporting it to excel but the varbinary data type is only showing System.Byte[] without the image. There is a way to solve that but i have to download all the images to a path then upload them again. Just i am looking for a way to export any type of image, lets say Gif to excel directly from the datagridview